# iOS : Custom UISegmentedControl does not adjust when orientation is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

My orginal portrait view is like this

[image]

When I change the orientation and rotate the simulator left or right, I get

[image]

When I click on any tab other than "Profile", the tab bar is adjusted the way I want.

I am using custom UISegmentedControl on navigation control. How to adjust the views for tab-bars immediately when the rotation of the screen is changed.

Using Xcode 4.6 and deployment is for all iOS versions.

Here's my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Tapped outside to hide keyboard
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapped];

    tapped.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];

    profileSegmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Profile", @"List", @"Scan", @"Collaborate", @"Logout", nil]];


    [profileSegmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(profileButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {
            UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.5f];
            NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
            [profileSegmentControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            profileSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 318, 30);
        }
        else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        {
            profileSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 470, 30);
        }
        else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            profileSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 470, 30);
        }
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    }
    else    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {

            profileSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 758, 40);
        }
        else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        {
            profileSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 994, 40);
        }
        else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            profileSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 994, 40);
        }
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    }

    profileSegmentControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    profileSegmentControl.momentary = YES;

    //[profileSegmentControl sizeToFit];

    UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
    [bar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];



    UIBarButtonItem *profileSegmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:profileSegmentControl];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = profileSegmentBarItem;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return [self.presentingViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}



-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to adjust uisegmentcontrol in orientation change delegate by setting its frame according to your requirments

Answer (score 0):

Implemented by cut pasting the following code in - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations method

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {
            UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.5f];
            NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
            [profileSegmentControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            profileSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 318, 30);
        }
        else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        {
            profileSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 470, 30);
        }
        else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            profileSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 470, 30);
        }
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    }
    else    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {

            profileSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 758, 40);
        }
        else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        {
            profileSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 994, 40);
        }
        else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            profileSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 994, 40);
        }
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    }
```